# Check if classname exists on html element, if yes replace it, if not add

Tags: javascript

How can I check if a class exists already on my html element? for e.g. if it already has first,second or third then I want to replace it with the one that I am passing.
Instead of doing like this which is wrong

```
initHeader(classNames[0])
initHeader(classNames[1])
initHeader(classNames[0])
```

```js
const banner = document.querySelector('header');

const classNames = [{
    image_url: "first"
  },
  {
    image_url: "second"
  },
  {
    image_url: "third"
  }
]

function initHeader(bg) {
  //check if one of the classes already exists on banner, if yes replace it, if not just add.
  banner.classList.add(`${bg.image_url}`)
}

initHeader(classNames[0])
initHeader(classNames[1])
initHeader(classNames[0])
```

```css
.first {
  background-image: url('https://www.investmentmonitor.ai/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2021/10/Warsaw-skyline-2-934x657-1.jpg');
}

.second{
  background-image: url('https://i.natgeofe.com/k/04665f4a-3f8d-4b62-8ca3-09ce7dfc5a20/france-eiffel-tower_4x3.jpg');
}

header {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the `initHeader` function to leave the banner with only one class at the end of it, right?
You can basically remove all 3, and add the relevant one:

```
function initHeader(bg) {
  banner.classList.remove("first", "second", "third");
  banner.classList.add(`${bg.image_url}`);
}
```

Or, you can check if each one exists before removing (no real difference here)
div.classList.contains("foo")

```
function initHeader(bg) {
  const classes = banner.classList;
  if (classes.contains("first") classes.remove("first");
  //...similar for rest...
  classes.add(`${bg.image_url}`);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> How can I check if a class exists already on my html element?

Use `Element.classList.contains()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains